# How to store items in a 2d array where the next row will start with the previous rows last item - C#

Tags: c#, algorithm, matrix

So basically im trying to figure out a way to store items in a n*n matrix where the next row will start with the previous rows last item. Im kinda new to c# so i would appreciate new ways to solve this problem too.
The final result should be something like this:

1. Let's say we have a string "Hello",
2. This string then it would need to be stored in a 2D array like so:
   Hello
   oHell
   loHel
   lloHe
   elloH

Thus far i just did the easy one where i printed the same string in each row:

```
string test = "Hello";
int mLength = test.Length;
char[] charArr = test.ToCharArray();
char[][] matrix = new char[mLength][];

//Inserting into the matrix
for(int i = 0; i < mLength; i++)
{
    matrix[i] = new char[mLength];
    
    for(int j = 0; j < mLength; j++)
    {
        matrix[i][j] = charArr[j];
    }
}

//For printing the matrix
for(int m = 0; m < matrix.Length; m++)
{
    for(int n = 0; n < matrix[m].Length; n++)
    {
        Console.Write(matrix[m][n]);
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of:

```
matrix[i][j] = charArr[j];
```

you should use:

```
matrix[i][j] = charArr[(j + mLength - i) % mLength];
```

So:

```
for (int i = 0; i < mLength; i++)
{
    matrix[i] = new char[mLength];

    for (int j = 0; j < mLength; j++)
    {
        matrix[i][j] = charArr[(j + mLength - i) % mLength];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string inputString1 = "Hello";
int length = inputString1.Length;
char[][] matrix = new char[length][];

// Create the rotated strings and store them in the matrix
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
{
    matrix[i] = new char[length];

    // Rotate the string and store it in the matrix
    for (int j = 0; j < length; j++)
    {
        matrix[i][j] = inputString1[(length - i + j) % length];
    }
}

// For printing the matrix
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < length; j++)
    {
        Console.Write(matrix[i][j]);
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Comment: This does not produce the correct output.